# How can i apply a specific equation to all turtles?

Tags: netlogo

when i  applied  an equation to all turtles (the nodes is taken from a database), the first value is calculated only and it is repeated over the rest? 
There are different values for each node(a,b,c,d)
is there another way  instead of ask turtles ?? i do not know what the wrong ?

```
  ask turtles [ set total  (a+b)*w +(d+c)* w1 / 4]
```

This is code execution
(turtle 14): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 21): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 35): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 19): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 24): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 39): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 15): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 54): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 40): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 47): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 36): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 60): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 41): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 20): 0.0018243243243243246
(turtle 31): 0.0018243243243243246

Answer (score 2):

There is nowhere near enough information to answer your question since you haven't provided the values of any of the variables. As I suggested on your previous (now deleted) question, you need to check that the variables going into the equation are what you think they are. For example:

```
ask turtles
[ type "a is " print a
  type "b is " print b
  type "c is " print c
  type "d is " print d
  type "w is " print w
  type "w1 is " print w1
  set total  (a+b)*w +(d+c)* w1 / 4
  print total
]
```

Comment: a b c d  Are different values for the centrality for each node

Comment: I deleted the previous question because it has become incomprehensible, and
It is not appropriate  to write the complete code inside a question

Comment: My suggestion was not asking what the different variables represent, it was to print out the values for the variables to see if they are what you think they are. Lots of these types of problems are because a value is 0 because it hasn't been set for example. So I am giving you a debugging process. You claim that the values of a, b etc are different but you haven't done a print to prove that. If the turtles have different values, then the equation will give different answers. Since it doesn't give different answers, there is something wrong but we can't simply guess what that may be.

Comment: The variables were printed directly in csv file,

Comment: That doesn't change my answer. Your code will correctly produce different results from the same equation if your inputs are different for each turtle. The only way to diagnose this is to print out the input variable values to see which variables are wrong. You need to put print statements for each variable immediately before the equation is applied to see what values are being entered into the equation. Then you can backtrack further to see why it's wrong. The error is not in the line you have provided and you are refusing to provide any other code or numbers. What do you think we can do?

Answer (score 0):

As someone has already stated there doesn't seem to be enough information provided. From what I can see you may want to create a turtles own variable. This gives each turtle its own variable to hold. For example if you give turtles a health variable of 100 each turtle can individually change their health value independently. I'm not sure if this what you are looking for though